# Java JFrame_JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

I am having a problem using JFrame and JPanel. My entire code is given below:

```
class GUIExample
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Creating the frame
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Chat Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Creating data panel and a label and a text box        
        JPanel dataPanel=new JPanel();
        dataPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        dataPanel.setLocation(0,0);
        dataPanel.setOpaque(true);
        dataPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        dataPanel.setSize(200,200);

        JLabel lblName=new JLabel("Enter Text: ");
        lblName.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lblName.setBounds(0, 10, 2, 2);

        dataPanel.add(lblName);

        frame.add(dataPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Please help what is happening with the program

Comment: You have not added a text box, unlike you mentioned on the code comment.

Comment: You set a layout manager to you container and then try and change the position and size of the components you're adding to it, no I can't see this been a problem at all. You might like to have a good read of [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 2):

It shows a Window with a Label says 'Enter Text:'
what's the question??

Comment: I think your reply was supposed to be in comments, not in answer section.

Comment: In my system, the window is shown but the label is not shown. Even if I use a text box, it does not show the label and text box in the output JFrame. I am confused where the problem actually lies.

Comment: @vandey AFAIK users with reputations less that 50 can not post comments everywhere ...

Comment: @user1673627 whats your OS? maybe changing  dataPanel.setOpaque() to false help you! beside there is no textfield defined here!!